# Problem with Transparency in beamer appears black

Tags: beamer, transparency, auto-pst-pdf, ps2pdf

All was working perfect, I just Check for update and applied it from the MikTex Console and now when I work with beamer and use PS to PDF I get:

%%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dNOSAFER

and the pdf generated is not right but the ps does. I use \begin{example}  \end{example}, but it does not show it correctly, look the image, in general if I use \begin{block} \end{block} appears in the same way, block with or without title.

I use:

WinEdt --> Build: 20180507  (v. 10.3) - 64-bit
MikTeX --> Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 21.1)
Gsview 6.0
Ghostscript 9.52 (2020-03-19)

What can I do to solve this? Thank you in advance.

[image]

My example,

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{rose} 
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}  
\begin{document}
    \frame{\frametitle{Distribuciones conjuntas (cont.)}
            \begin{example}
            Se lanza un dado 2 veces consecutivas.\\ \vspace*{0.3cm}
            $X_1$ $\Longrightarrow$ máximo valor obtenido en los dos lanzamientos.\\ \vspace*{0.3cm}
            $X_2$ $\Longrightarrow$ suma de los valores obtenidos en los dos lanzamientos.\\ \vspace*{0.3cm}
            Encontrar la función de distribución de probabilidad conjunta de $X_1$ y $X_2$ y la función de distribución acumulada conjunta de $X_1$ y $X_2$.
            \end{example}
            \transboxout%
          }
\end{document}
```

Comment: as the error says you probably need to call ghostscript with `dNOSAFER` (and perhaps also with `-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY`), but as you didn't provide an example which can be tested it is difficult to say.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I just add an example. Thank you

Comment: You seem to use MikTeX's built-in GhostScript, which may be old, and not the vanilla one (9.52) which is indeed required for transparency. And add `-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY` to the `ps2pdf` command line. Also, transparency is a PDF feature and will not be visible in the intermediate PS (looked at in GSView). Open the final PDF in a PDF viewer instead (AcroRd, or Sumatra, for instance.) Otherwise, your example looks ok, though I'd use the `frame` environment instead of the `\frame` command.

Comment: miktex ghostscript is too old, but you can use an external one by setting an environment variable, see https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/218. Why do you use the ps-route instead of pdflatex?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer and AlexG  Thank you for your answer. I do not how to implement the command line you suggest. I use PS to PDF because in the original file I have many figures in EPS.

Comment: A current pdflatex can convert eps on the fly.